# How to end game automatically in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, youtube

I followed a tutorial on YouTube (available at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c47QYgsJrWc)) to show how to drag/drop items in my game. Does anyone know how I could adapt the code to have the game automatically end or change scene when all tiles have been placed in the available slots? I'd also like to know if there's any way to restrict the user from dropping a tile onto a slot which has one on it already? 
This is all the source code I have already:

Slots source code

```
public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler {
    public GameObject item {
        get {
            if(transform.childCount>0){
                return transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    #region IDropHandler implementation
    public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(!item){
            DragHandeler.itemBeingDragged.transform.SetParent (transform);
            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy<IHasChanged>(gameObject,null,(x,y) => x.HasChanged ());
        }
    }
```

DragHandler source code:

```
public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        startPosition = transform.position;
        startParent = transform.parent;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDragHandler implementation

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = eventData.position;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEndDragHandler implementation

    public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = null;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
        if(transform.parent == startParent){
            transform.position = startPosition;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer after you added code and described what you want. I think that my solution should work fine. Please check below.

Comment: I've updated my answer again a lot, after your new questions in comments below. Please check it. =)

Comment: Hi @Lloyd. So, how is your progress? Can you please accept the answer to close the issue already? I've already helped you with 5 different issues, after many comments and editing of post. I hope you implemented it all and have good progress on your project, and hope you understand... :)

Comment: OMG I am so sorry @Dest for not getting back to you! I completely forgot! My apologies. All your solutions worked! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change scene you need to use this:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(scenename);
```

Here is [LoadScene documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html).

If you need to also help you with logic where to put it in your project - please add your code and some more explanation about what you're doing, instead of link to 22 minutes of some tutorial.

---

**Update:**

Here is the way for you to change scene when all slots are full:

```
public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if(!item)
    {
        DragHandeler.itemBeingDragged.transform.SetParent (transform);
        ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy<IHasChanged>(gameObject,null,(x,y) => x.HasChanged ());

        // This code will check if all slots are full and load new scene if they are
        // If you already have an array/list of all your slots, you can replace this "FindObjectsOfType" with it
        Slot[] allSlots = FindObjectsOfType<Slot>();
        bool areAllBackpackSlotsFull = true;
        foreach (Slot slot in allSlots)
        {
            if (slot.isBackpack == true && slot.item == null)
            {
                areAllBackpackSlotsFull = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (areAllBackpackSlotsFull)
        {
            string nextSceneName = "YourScene"; // Place the name of scene you want to load next
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneName);
        }
    }
}
```

You also asked:

> I'd also like to know if there's any way to restrict the user from
>   dropping a tile onto a slot which has one on it already?

But I see that it seems already implemented in your code. There is check if current item is null in the "OnDrop" function of Slot, that should do exactly what you want - place tile only if slot is empty. So it's already should be restricted. Are you sure that it's not?

---

**Update 2:**

Update for your new question about backpack and inventory. You can just add some bool variable to Slot class to distinguish backpack from inventory:

```
public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public bool isBackpack = false;
    ...
```

Then in the editor mark in all backpack Slots the "isBackpack" variable true. This would be simple and convenient way to distinguish them.

Also I've updated the code above (that checks is backpack full), so it would check only backpack slots now.

---

**Update 3:**

I've noticed that you've asked yet another question in comments:

> Would there be a way to lock a tile once it has been dragged from the inventory and dropped to the 'backpack'? i.e. that they can't move it again?

It's obviously not related to the original post and question, but ok, I'll try to help with this one too...

I think that something like this can achieve what you want (I've changed your DragHandler code):

```
public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Slot currentSlot = gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Slot>();
    if (currentSlot.isBackpack == false)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        startPosition = transform.position;
        startParent = transform.parent;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
    else
    {
        itemBeingDragged = null;
    }
}

#endregion

#region IDragHandler implementation

public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (itemBeingDragged != null)
        transform.position = eventData.position;
}

#endregion

#region IEndDragHandler implementation

public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (itemBeingDragged != null)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = null;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
        if(transform.parent == startParent)
            transform.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

---

**P.S.** I've already helped you with like 5 different questions. Please, if you have any more questions, not related to the original post - I would suggest to accept the answer to close this issue, and ask other questions in separate posts with new updated code and info (and you can add the link to this post in new posts(questions)). Because it's just not the right way to use this site, to ask new non related questions in comments and constantly update question and answer, it's just inconvenient.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I really do appreciate it.You're right, sorry for not giving any code. I'll update my question with my code!

Comment: Waw, thank you so much for your help! I'm away from the PC at the moment but will try your code later! It's strange regarding the OnDrop function. You're right it should work. Would there be another way to achieve the same thing? I know I'm asking a lot here but could I ask another thing? Would there be a way to lock a tile once it has been dragged from the inventory and dropped to the 'backpack'? i.e. that they can't move it again? I would though want to allow them to pick up a tile from the inventory and re-place it back in the inventory i.e. that it's not locked if it's not in the backpack

Comment: Oh, I see, there are "Slot"s in both inventory and backpack... In the code you provided there is no way to distinguish between them (backpack Slots from inventory Slots). So I would need more code/info from you to help with this new question. Explain how to distinguish backpack from inventory, maybe there is more code? or something in editor?

Comment: there's only the one code for all of the Slots! :/ the way the tutorial has done it is that you select all of the slots then Add Component which links them all to the same Slot script..... sorry I should have clarified earlier, the inventory is where the user selects available cards and drags/drops them into their personal backpack. Hope that made sense?

Comment: Sorry @Dest I forgot to tag you in my previous comment. Do you think I'll need to create a Slot code for the inventory and backpack? i.e. 1 script each? I could then link the inventory script to the inventory slots and same principle for the backpack slots? Although how would I get both scripts to interact? i.e. how would the inventory script know when all backpack slots are occupied?

Comment: Hi again, @Lloyd. With new information and new question, I've updated my answer again with the way for you to distinguish between your backpack and inventory, and updated previous code to check only backpack Slots.

Comment: @Lloyd, I've noticed yet another question in your previous comment about locking the backpack items. So I've updated my answer again with solution to this one too. Please check, I hope it helps too; and check my "P.S." comment there too please :)